How to extract text from the response in Sikuli
I am writing Sikuli code in Java using eclipse IDE. I have a scenario of a chat box. I input a string and then it gives the response in the chat window itself. I want to extract that complete response text. How can I do it? Also, I then want to take a screenshot of it.
I could just do the match. But that's not what I wanted to do.
Match match = screen.find(expectedPattern);
Assert.assertNotNull(match, "Image matched");

